# Looking for a low cost android phone which is compatible with the clubhouse app

Tags: android, mobile-phone

I am searching for finding some low price android phone (+- $50) which be proper for installing the [clubhouse app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.clubhouse.app&hl=fa&gl=US), so I know the clubhouse needs the android V7 for it, and I found the [INVENCE H2](https://www.megadropshop.com/products/invens-h2-black/) mobile phone with android V10 and 1Gb ram but I was unable to install the clubhouse app on it. I'd as such like to get a low price android phone to exclusively use for installing and using the clubhouse.

if possible I like to have some comment and answer for finding the cheapest price mobile phone.

Thanks.

Comment: And what is the exact buget?

Comment: Thanks @Iesu85, I am in middle east and my budget is low ( almost 50$), and I guess I can find some second hand mobile phone with android 7,there.

Answer (score 0):

I can´t comment, because of this I will write an answer (I hope this is fine!). You probably don´t want to miss on performance completely. Maybe you could check out used Xiaomi phones in your region? Xiaomi offers pretty good performance for the price. In general you could use a compare site to figure good stats and prices out.

Maybe you could also ask in the [Android Stack](https://android.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: [Android.se] explicitly disallows recommendation questions, such as apps and phones recommendation.

Comment: Oh, I didn´t know that! Sorry! :) But good to know in this case! Thanks a lot!